# NoMethodError in ruby module

Tags: ruby, module

```
module Add
def addition
    sum=1+2
    puts sum
end
a=Add.addition
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and why I am getting this error->

undefined method `addition' for Add:Module (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing class methods and instance methods. Your definition:

```
module Add
  def addition
    ...
  end
end
```

defines methods on instances of `Add` whereas you called a method on the module `Add`. If you want to define a class/module method, you need to define like:

```
module Add
  def self.addition
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call it directly, define it as a directly accessible method:

```
def self.addition
  # ...
end
```

Or you can always rework this using:

```
module Add
  # ...(methods)...

  extend self
end
```

Where that will automatically promote all mixin-type methods as being directly accessible.

You can also tag them more selectively like this:

```
module Add
  def addition
    # ...
  end
  module_method :addition
end
```

That method is then available either as `Add.addition` or if some other module or class calls `include Add`.